# What does the Catholic Church teach about the communication that takes place among the Persons of the Trinity?

Tags: catholicism, trinity, communication

We read in Mtt 24:36 (NRSVCE):

> But about that day and hour no one knows, neither the angels of heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father.

Here, Jesus does not mention  Holy Spirit being privy to the `secret' about the end of the world which,  according to the Lord,  only the Father knows. That implies that there is  communication going on among the three Persons of the Trinity,with the Will of the Father being revealed to the Son and the Holy Spirit at the ordained time. My question therefore is: What does the Catholic Church teach about the communication that takes place among the Persons of the Trinity ?

Comment: The Catholic Church teaches that the Three Persons differ only relationally. Thus they share one divine intellect, and hence they all, as one God, know everything. Jesus, being the incarnation of the Son, is both fully divine and fully human, and therefore he has two intellects: one divine, and one human. This is part of the doctrine of the "hypostatic union." While Jesus in his divine intellect as the Son knows everything the Father knows, in his human intellect he knows only what has been put into it by God.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Jeh's comment, a Catholic would reject the premise that this passage implies the Holy Spirit does not know the day and hour. There could be a number of reasons why Christ would not have mentioned the Holy Spirit here. It could be that, for the Jews He was teaching, it was understood that the Spirit of the Lord was not distinct in knowledge from the Father. The Jewish understanding of God as a Father and as a Spirit is well-attested to ([Holy Spirit in Judaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Spirit_in_Judaism)) ([God the Father in the Old Testament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_the_Father#:%7E:text=Old%20Testament,-According%20to%20Marianne&text=In%20the%20Hebrew%20Bible%2C%20in,the%20fatherly%20role%20of%20protector.)). It could be that He had not yet taught His disciples about the doctrine of the Holy Trinity. It could be something else we are unaware of.

But a Catholic could not say that the Holy Spirit, nor even the Son *in His divinity*, does not know the day nor the hour, as this would break either Divine Simplicity (a real distinction of intellects) or the oneness of the Holy Trinity, both foundational doctrines to the faith.